# Elastic Search Range Query on Array of Integers

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data like below;

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "count": [1, 2]
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "count": [1, 1]
}
```

When I search for a range [1,1] I want to see only the data with the one id = 2, but the data id=1 also comes

My query is like;

```
GET some_index/_search
{

"query": {
  //some query logic
},

 "post_filter": {
    "filter":{
      "range": {
        "count": {
          "gte": 1,
          "lte": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}

How can I do this efficiently and elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your required use case, by using a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "count": [1, 2]
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "count": [1, 1]
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "count": [0, 1]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "count": {
            "gte": 1,
            "lte": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "count": {
              "gt": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "count": {
              "lt": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65297212",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "count": [
            1,
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @PeerNet glad I could help you :)